# How a single variable can have different value on the basis of host instance in Ansible?

Tags: deployment, ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-template

I am having  `"appInstanceName": "{{appname_from_template}}"` in my ansible template and I am manitaining `appname_from_template` in my `group_vars/all` file.

And when deploying I want this `{{appname_from_template}}` to be replaced with `"endpoint_1"` on host1 and `"endpoint_2"` on host2.

But I am not sure how a single variable can have different value based on the instance it's deploying.

Please let me know if there is any way to do?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Given the *group_vars/all*

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/all
appname_from_template: endpoint_maintained_in_groupvars_all
```

you can override the variable *appname_from_template* on precedence higher than 7. See [Understanding variable precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#understanding-variable-precedence). *" The variable can have different values based on the instance"* if you put it into the

- *host_vars* in the inventory file (precedence 8) or
- *host_vars* in the inventory's directory (precedence 9) or
- *host_vars* in the playbook's directory (precedence 10).

For example

```yaml
shell> cat host_vars/host1
appname_from_template: endpoint_1

shell> cat host_vars/host2
appname_from_template: endpoint_2
```

Then the playbook

```yaml
- hosts: host1,host2,host3
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: appname_from_template
```

use *host_vars* for host1 and host2, and *group_vars* for host3

```yaml
ok: [host1] => 
  appname_from_template: endpoint_1
ok: [host3] => 
  appname_from_template: endpoint_maintained_in_groupvars_all
ok: [host2] => 
  appname_from_template: endpoint_2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Vladimir!
I got another solution using host_vars.. here you can check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50182388/8548451. This worked like charm!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by defining my variables for host1 and host2 in `host_vars/host1` and `host_vars/host2`

Example: for host1 
Inside `host_vars/host1` file 
appname_from_template: endpoint_1

Inside `host_vars/host2` file 
appname_from_template: endpoint_2

And this worked like charm!